# Identity Server 4 Cant Validate My Access Token

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, identityserver4

I am using Asp.net Core 3.1 Web Api For Generate Api And Use Identity Server 4(3.1.2) With asp.net identity core In Same Project(Both In One Project) To Authenticate User.
Identity Server 4 Generate Access Token But When Call Api With Postman,EveryTime Return 401.
This is my Identity Server 4 Config:

```
 "IdentityServerSetting": {
    "IdentityServerAuthority": "https://localhost:5000",
    "IdentityResources": [
      "openID"
    ],
    "ApiResources": [
      {
        "Name": "MadPay",
        "DisplayName": "MadPay Api",
        "UserClaims": [
          "name",
          "Email"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "Client": [
      {
        "AccessTokenLifeTime": 3600,
        "AllowedGrantTypes": "password",
        "ClientId": "angular",
        "AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken": "true",
        "AlwaysSendClientClaims": "true",
        "AllowCorsOrigins": [ "https://localhost:5000" ],
        "RequireClientSecret": "false",
        "AllowedScopes": [ "OpenId", "MadPay" ],
        "AllowOfflineAccess": "true"
      }
    ]
  }
```

This Is My ConfigureService

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<JwtConfig>(_configuration.GetSection(nameof(JwtConfig)));
            services.Configure<IdentityServerSetting>(_configuration.GetSection(nameof(IdentityServerSetting)));

            services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork<ApplicationDBContext>>();

            services.AddMapperConfigurations();
            services.AddServices();

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDBContext>(opt =>
            {
                opt.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("ApplicationConnection"));
            });

            services.AddMvcCore(opt => opt.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
             .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0)
             .AddAuthorization()
             .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);

            services.AddResponseCaching();
            services.AddIdentityServerConfig(_identityServerSetting);
            services.AddApiAuthorization();

            services.AddCors();
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
            });
        }
```

This Is My Configure

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostEnvironment env)
        {
            IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            //app.UseHsts();

            app.UseCors(i => i.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
            app.AddExceptionHandling();
            app.UseResponseCaching();
            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseHttpContext();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

AddApiAuthorization Fuction

```
 public static void AddApiAuthorization(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
                .AddJwtBearer(opt =>
                 {
                     opt.Authority = "https://localhost:5000";
                     opt.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                     //opt.Audience = "MadPay";
                     opt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                     {
                         ValidateAudience = false
                     };
                 });

 services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, PermissionAuthorizationHandler>();

            services.AddAuthorization(option =>
                option.AddPolicy("Permission", builder =>
                    builder.AddRequirements(new PermissionRequirement()).RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                )
            );
}
```

AddIdentityServerConfig Fuction

```
 public static void AddIdentityServerConfig(this IServiceCollection services, IdentityServerSetting config)
        {
            var finalConfig = MapJsonToConfig(config);

            services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(opt =>
            {
                opt.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                opt.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                opt.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;

                opt.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;

                opt.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
                opt.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDBContext>()
            .AddUserManager<AppUserManager>()
            //.AddSignInManager<AppSignInManager>()
            .AddErrorDescriber<AppErrorDescriberService>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
            })

                    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(finalConfig.IdentityResources)
                    .AddInMemoryApiResources(finalConfig.Apis)
                    .AddInMemoryClients(finalConfig.Clients)
                    .AddAspNetIdentity<User>()
                    .AddResourceOwnerValidator<AppIdentityPasswordValidator<User>>();
        }
```

This is My Paload from access token

```
{
  "nbf": 1597823415,
  "exp": 1597827015,
  "iss": "https://localhost:5000",
  "aud": "MadPay",
  "client_id": "angular",
  "sub": "1",
  "auth_time": 1597823413,
  "idp": "local",
  "name": "osali",
  "scope": [
    "MadPay",
    "offline_access"
  ],
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ]
}
```

And For Call Api Use This url : https://localhost:5000/...
And Send Token in Authorization Header : Bearer ....

i think Issued access token is not a problem.
I spent a few days And Cant Understand Why is not working and very confused what is wrong!!

Comment: can you post a copy of the token and what does your postman request look like? Do you use any authorization policies in the API? or how is the API controllers protected?

Comment: I Edited my question and add more detail.

Comment: I updated my answer below, does that help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set all the token validation parameters to false, and then enable them one by one, to see what triggers the error.

```
            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateAudience = false;
            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false;
            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateLifetime = false;
            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateTokenReplay = false;
```

You can also try to enable the following and check the response from the API in postman or Fiddler.

```
            //True if token validation errors should be returned to the caller.
            options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
```

How is the API Controllers protected? Do you use any authorization policies?

In your API startup you should not use IdentityServer, instead you should use the AddMyJwtBearer method. and in your configure method you should use:

```
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
```

Here's a sample startup.cs class for a typical API:

```
public class Startup
{
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMyJwtBearer(options =>
        {

            options.Audience = "payment";
            options.Authority = "https://localhost:6001/";

            //True if token validation errors should be returned to the caller.
            options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;

            //If the signing key is not found, do a refresh from the JWKS endpoint
            //This allows for automatic recovery in the event of a  key rollover
            options.RefreshOnIssuerKeyNotFound = true;

            //Gets or sets if HTTPS is required for the metadata address or authority.
            //Should always be true in production!
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;

            //True if the token should be stored in the AuthenticationProperties
            //after a successful authorization.
            options.SaveToken = true;

            //Parameters
            options.TokenValidationParameters.ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
            options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "role";

        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();


        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic:
[Troubleshooting JwtBearer authentication problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/02/21/troubleshooting-jwtbearer-authentication-problems-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: This isnt work,I Add Project to Gitlab,[link](https://gitlab.com/my_angular_project/madpay) to see all of code.Thank You

Comment: In Api Project Use IdentityServer4 And Asp.net Core Identity Together,If  not use IdentityServer then https://localhost:5000/connect/token cant access and cant generate token

Comment: this error isnt helfull?trce: IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter[0]
      No endpoint entry found for request path: /api/WeatherForecast

Comment: in my example, try to remove the /api/ part from the URL. does that help? or change my pattern to  template: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");  I see that your code in GitLab is using old ASP.NET Core style of coding. Its more modern to use  app.UseRouting(); and  app.UseEndpoints().

Comment: Not Fixed! My Api Url and Identity Server url is same: https://localhost:5000 and both use https, Is it wrong??

Comment: why do you have the same url for both? when in your gitlab repository have different projects for the API and IdentitiyServer? does a get to WeatherForecastController  work? it should work because its not protected using the authorize attribute. its easier to keep the code sane by putting them on different URL/services. it makes things much clearer... mixing it makes it much harder to reason about.

Comment: Yes I I decide To Seprate Identity From Api.Thank U Sooo much

Answer (score 0):

you are missing below :-

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

can you add above in the **startup.cs** Configure method in api and give it a try ?

Comment: @AliBelyani- which api endpoint are you calling ? if its the weatherForecast get endpoint, you may want to check the permission attribute if that's giving you the desired result.